# Html.DropDownListFor value duplicates when add a Preselect value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

My code is like this

```
List<String> ddlData = new List<string>();
ddlData.Add("--Select--");
ddlData.Add("Manager");

@Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.myddl, new SelectList(ddlData), "Manager", new { @class = "custom-select" })
```

Everything looks fine to me, But when Dropdown loads it loads with two "Manager" in it. I want only `ddlData`  items to populate and preselect "Manager".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `ddlData` is defined inside the view you could try:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => ddlData,
    ddlData.Select(d => { return new SelectListItem() { Selected = (d.ToString() == "Manager"),  Text = d, Value = d }; }),
    null, new { @class = "custom-select" })
```

But if the `ddlData` is passed to the view as a parameter and the view model defined as
`@model IList<string>` the below line will populate teh `DropDownList` correctly too:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.GetEnumerator().Current,
    Model.Select(d =>
    {
        return new SelectListItem() { Selected = (d.ToString() == "Manager"), Text = d, Value = d };
    }),
    null, new { @class = "custom-select" })
```